# How to create a GitPython Repo object with different git-dir and work-tree paths?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

From the command line I use to do this:

```
$git --git-dir=/opt/git/annotation.git --work-tree=/path/to/worktree/ commit  -m 'commit message command line'
```

Now, I have to call git from a python script using GitPython and this is what I tried:

```
# script.py
from git import *

repo = Repo('/opt/git/annotation.git')
repo.index.add('/path/to/worktree/')
repo.git.add('/path/to/worktree/')
repo.git.commit(m='commit message from script')
```

I had:

```
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 54, in git_commit
    repo.index.add('/path/to/worktree/')
    ...
    raise InvalidGitRepositoryError("require non-bare repository")
InvalidGitRepositoryError: require non-bare repository
```

Comment: I know little about GitPython, but since the log says 'require non-bare repository', I guess /path/to/worktree/ is a bare repo initialized by `git init --bare` or `git clone --bare`. A bare repo has no work tree, so it's not proper to set a bare repo path as a work tree.